# Rspec - how to test that a nested service is instanciated appropriately and the appropriate method is called on this instance

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, automated-tests, rspec-rails, rspec3

Suppose I have a class that is supposed to call a service multiple times with different arguments

```
class MyExecutor
  def perform
    targets.each do |target|
      MyService.new(target).call
    end
  end
end

class MyService
  def initialize(target)
    @target = target
  end

  def call
    @target.do_something
  end
end
```

Assume I want to write a test on `MyExecutor`, generating data so that I have at least 2 targets, and I want to test that the service `MyService` is called appropriately on all targets.

When I had only one target, I could use `expect_any_instance_of().to receive(:call)` but then I was not really testing the instanciation with appropriate params, and then this syntax is deprecated  (cf [comment here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance))

```
describe MyExecutor
  context 'with one target'
    it 'calls the MyService appropriately'
      expect_any_instance_of(MyService).to receive(:call)
      MyExecutor.perform
    end
  end
end
```

Suppose I have multiple targets, **how can I test that the MyService is  instanciated twice, once with each relevant target, and that on each of those instanciated services, the `call` method is called appropriately** What is the proper non-deprecated way to test this ?

*Implicit question : (is this the right way to approach the problem ?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rspec 3.8 syntax:

```
describe MyExecutor do
  subject(:executor) { described_class.new }

  describe '#perform' do
    subject(:perform) { executor.perform }

    let(:target1) { instance_double('target' }
    let(:target2) { instance_double('target' }
    let(:service1) { instance_double(MyService, call: true) }
    let(:service2) { instance_double(MyService, call: true) }

    before do 
      allow(MyExecutor).to receive(:targets).and_return([target1, target2])
      allow(MyService).to receive(:new).with(target1).and_return(service1)
      allow(MyService).to receive(:new).with(target2).and_return(service2)

      perform
    end

    it 'instantiates MyService once for each target' do
      expect(MyService).to have_received(:new).with(target1).ordered
      expect(MyService).to have_received(:new).with(target2).ordered
    end

    it 'calls MyService once for each target' do
      expect(service1).to have_received(:call)
      expect(service2).to have_received(:call)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that using `.ordered` allows you to specify the exact order of operations.

Note that doubling MyService `.with` a specific parameter allows you to control the return value for that specific parameter.

Comment: Are you implying that in RSpec 3.8 it's a better practice to use spies with `have_received` than using `expect().to receive()` ?

Comment: Also, since we already test that our doubles receive the `call` method, is it really useful to test the service class has received :new ? Or it it, as you mentioned, only useful because we are testing instanciation order with `.ordered` ?

Comment: Both syntaxes work. I was just pointing out that the syntax I was using was 3.8 compliant. I think it's more a preference than a better practice.

Comment: Regarding testing the instantiation: what I'm testing there is that I am creating the correct collaborating objects based on their parameters. In other words, I'm more concerned with the `.with` clause than the `.ordered` clause. We just need to use `.ordered` to tell Rspec to expect the calls in a specific order.

Comment: `let(:target1) { instance_double('target' }` has a syntax error it should be `let(:target1) { instance_double('target') }` it's missing the closing paren.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm understanding your need:

```
 describe MyExecutor do
   context 'with one target' do
     it 'calls the MyService appropriately' do
       target1 = double("TargetClass")
       target2 = double("TargetClass")
       allow(MyExecutor).to receive(:targets).and_return([target1, target2])

       service1 = double(MyService, call: nil)
       service2 = double(MyService, call: nil)
       expect(MyService).to receive(:new).with(target1).once.and_return(service1)
       expect(MyService).to receive(:new).with(target2).once.and_return(service2)

       MyExecutor.perform
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Oh, so `expect().to receive` also works with instanciation via :new ? Since the method we actually implement is `:initialize`, I wonder how this actually works in RSpec... do you have any ref to the documentation about this ? I mean this does feels intuitive, but I don't understand why this works in practice.

Comment: The method that `MyService` receives is the class method`.new` which creates the object and calls the instance method `#initialize` on your behalf. That's why you mock the call to `.new`. See the docs here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Class.html#method-i-new